# ERB: iterate over an array and output each value as part of a one line string

Tags: ruby, iteration, puppet, erb

I am trying to write a sudoers file by iterating over an array which comes from a puppet array.

Here is my puppet class. It defines an array `oracle_homes`

```
1 class oracle_home {
2   $oracle_homes = split($::oracle_homes, ',')
3   file { '/tmp/oracle_homes':
4     ensure  => file,
5     content => template('oracle/oracle.sudoer.erb'),
6   } 
7 }       
8 
9 require oracle_home
```

and here is the erb template.

```
 1 Defaults    env_keep += "ORACLE_BASE ORACLE_HOME TNS_ADMIN"
 2 
 3 <% @oracle_homes.each do |oracle_home| -%>
 4 Cmnd_Alias SQLPLUS = <%= oracle_home -%>/bin/sqlplus
 5 Cmnd_Alias SRVCTL  = <%= oracle_home -%>/bin/srvctl
 6 Cmnd_Alias VOTEDSK = <%= oracle_home -%>/bin/crsctl query css votedisk
 7 <% end -%>  
 8 
 9 Runas_Alias DB    = oracle, regdb
10 Runas_Alias GRID  = oracle, grid
11 
12 zabbix ALL = (GRID) NOPASSWD: VOTEDSK
13 zabbix ALL = (DB) NOPASSWD: SQLPLUS
14 zabbix ALL = (GRID) NOPASSWD: SRVCTL
15 
16 Defaults:zabbix !authenticate
17 Defaults:zabbix !syslog
```

From lines 3 to 6 I am trying to generate the `Cmnd_Alias` but the output is not what I need.

I get

```
 1  Defaults    env_keep += "ORACLE_BASE ORACLE_HOME TNS_ADMIN"
 2  
 3  Cmnd_Alias SQLPLUS = '/opt/oracle/regdb/product/12.1.0.2/dbhome_1'/bin/sqlplus
 4  Cmnd_Alias SRVCTL  = '/opt/oracle/regdb/product/12.1.0.2/dbhome_1'/bin/srvctl
 5  Cmnd_Alias VOTEDSK = '/opt/oracle/regdb/product/12.1.0.2/dbhome_1'/bin/crsctl query css votedisk
 6  Cmnd_Alias SQLPLUS = '/opt/oracle/regdb/product/11.2.0.4/dbhome_1'/bin/sqlplus
 7  Cmnd_Alias SRVCTL  = '/opt/oracle/regdb/product/11.2.0.4/dbhome_1'/bin/srvctl
 8  Cmnd_Alias VOTEDSK = '/opt/oracle/regdb/product/11.2.0.4/dbhome_1'/bin/crsctl query css votedisk
 9  
10  Runas_Alias DB    = oracle, regdb
11  Runas_Alias GRID  = oracle, grid
12  
13  zabbix ALL = (GRID) NOPASSWD: VOTEDSK
14  zabbix ALL = (DB) NOPASSWD: SQLPLUS
15  zabbix ALL = (GRID) NOPASSWD: SRVCTL
16  
17  Defaults:zabbix !authenticate
18  Defaults:zabbix !syslog
```

How can I change the iteration syntax to generate `Cmnd_Alias` lines like

```
Cmnd_Alias SQLPLUS = /opt/oracle/regdb/product/12.1.0.2/dbhome_1/bin/sqlplus, /opt/oracle/regdb/product/11.2.0.4/dbhome_1/bin/sqlplus
Cmnd_Alias VOTEDSK = /opt/oracle/regdb/product/12.1.0.2/dbhome_1/bin/crsctl query css votedisk, /opt/oracle/regdb/product/11.2.0.4/dbhome_1/bin/crsctl query css votedisk
```

Comment: I am not sure where the single quotes `'` in the generated versions are coming from. They a probably already part of `$::oracle_homes`. Can you please post how the original `$::oracle_homes` looks like?

Comment: Consider doing the fact value manipulation fully inside of the template instead of doing some inside the manifest and then passing it to the template for further manipulation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try to replace

```
3 <% @oracle_homes.each do |oracle_home| -%>
4 Cmnd_Alias SQLPLUS = <%= oracle_home -%>/bin/sqlplus
5 Cmnd_Alias SRVCTL  = <%= oracle_home -%>/bin/srvctl
6 Cmnd_Alias VOTEDSK = <%= oracle_home -%>/bin/crsctl query css votedisk
7 <% end -%>
```

with

```
Cmnd_Alias SQLPLUS = <%= @oracle_homes.map { |path| "#{path}/bin/sqlplus" }.join(', ') %>
Cmnd_Alias SRVCTL  = <%= @oracle_homes.map { |path| "#{path}/bin/srvctl" }.join(', ') %>
Cmnd_Alias VOTEDSK = <%= @oracle_homes.map { |path| "#{path}/bin/crsctl query css votedisk" }.join(', ') %>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sql_plus = []

srv_ctl = []

vote_desk = []

<% @oracle_homes.each do |oracle_home| -%>

    sql_plus << "#{oracle_home}/bin/sqlplus"

    srv_ctl << "#{oracle_home}/bin/srvctl"

    vote_desk << "#{oracle_home}/bin/crsctl query css votedisk"  
<% end -%>

Cmnd_Alias SQLPLUS = sql_plus.join(', ')

Cmnd_Alias SRVCTL  = srv_ctl.join(', ')

Cmnd_Alias VOTEDSK = vote_desk.join(', ')
```

Comment: I am more worried about the time complexity. Looping on the same array thrice.

Comment: it's still the wrong result? Can you help me where the flow is wrong